# Deleting rows based on multiple Joins and where statements in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have this below SQL statement that I am running on an Oracle database that I'd ideally like to put inside a stored procedure to be called through Java statements. However, I'd like to get the query working first. I have a few tables which have data and my query should satisfy a few conditions through Inner Joins before executing the Delete statement. So, here's the first query I had constructed. I keep getting **"SQL command not properly ended"** error:

```
Delete from ur 
  from ATESTuser_roles ur 
        Inner Join ATESTresource_roles rr 
               on ur.role_id = rr.role_id 
        Inner Join ATESTRESOURCES r 
               on rr.resource_id=r.RESOURCE_ID 
 where r.name='TestName' 
   and ur.user_id = '1401'
```

I also tried this version and it still dint work. I got a **`"ATESTRESOURCES"."RESOURCE_ID": invalid identifier error`** for this:

```
Delete from ATESTuser_roles 
 where ATESTuser_roles.role_id = ATESTresource_roles.role_id 
   and ATESTresources.name='TestName' 
   and ATESTresource_roles.resource_id=ATESTRESOURCES.RESOURCE_ID 
   and ATESTuser_roles.user_id = '1401'
```

I have a feeling I am missing something small but significant, and that I am missing some syntax, so any help is much appreciated.

P.S: I don't know how else to describe the relationship between the tables than the conditions in the query. However, if it is not clear, I can add additional information (don't want to turn this too wordy).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, you can't join multiple tables in a `delete` like that.  One option would be something like

```
Delete ATESTuser_roles ur 
 where exists( select 1
                 from ATESTresource_roles rr 
                      join ATESTRESOURCES r 
                   on rr.resource_id=r.RESOURCE_ID 
                where ur.role_id = rr.role_id 
                  and r.name='TestName' 
                  and ur.user_id = '1401' )
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to declare ON DELETE CASCADE in the ATESTuser_roles table. When this is done all you need to do is to run this query:

```
DELETE FROM ATESTuser_roles 
WHERE user_id = '1401'
```

Because of ON DELETE CASCADE the DB will remove any tuples in ATESTresource_roles where the foreign key (user_id) is equal 1401.

[ON DELETE CASCADE example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#i1015699)